# Pandas: How to find number of unique elements for one column coming from another column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'carrier': ['c1','c1','c1','c2','c2','c2','c3','c4','c5','c5'],
                   'airport': ['a1','a3','a1','a1','a2','a2','a3','a4','a4','a1'],
                  })

df

  carrier airport  
0      c1      a1  
1      c1      a3  
2      c1      a1  
3      c2      a1  
4      c2      a2  
5      c2      a2  
6      c3      a3  
7      c4      a4  
8      c5      a4  
9      c5      a1
```

I want to find the number of carriers that served the airport such that the airport is served by at least 2 different carriers.

How to do so?

Required output:

```
airport carrier n_carrier
a1  c1  3  # airport a1 is served by 3 distinct carriers
a3  c1  2  # airport a3 is served by 2 distinct carriers
a1  c2  3  # NOTE: here we do not see a2 because it has only
a3  c3  2  #       one carrier, so it is excluded
a4  c4  2
a4  c5  2  # airport a4 is served by 2 distinct carriers
a1  c5  3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'carrier': ['c1','c1','c1','c2','c2','c2','c3','c4','c5','c5'],
                   'airport': ['a1','a3','a1','a1','a2','a2','a3','a4','a4','a1'],
                  })

df['unique'] = df.groupby(['airport'])['carrier'].transform('nunique')
df[df['unique'].gt(1)].drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop = True)

carrier airport unique
0   c1     a1   3
1   c1     a3   2
2   c2     a1   3
3   c3     a3   2
4   c4     a4   2
5   c5     a4   2
6   c5     a1   3
```

This should give you what your looking for. Transform the groupby by number of uniques, then look at only ones greater than 1, and drop the duplicates